# Find all lines that contains given string

Tags: c#, regex, file, search, find

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"data.txt");
List<String> Spec= new List<String>();
while (file.EndOfStream != true)
{
    string s = file.ReadLine();
    Match m = Regex.Match(s, "Spec\\s");
    if (m.Success)
    {
        int a = Convert.ToInt16(s.Length);
        a = a - 5;
        string part = s.Substring(5, a);
        Spec.Add(part);
     }
}
```

I'm trying to get all lines that contains the word "Spec" and then a space character but I get an error when I run this program.

The details of the exception are as follows:

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

Could anyone assist me on figuring out why?

Text file:

```
ID  560
Spec    This ... bla bla 

blah...
blah...
bla bla 
bla
Category    Other
Price   $259.95 


ID  561
Spec    more blah blah...

blah...
blah...
bla bla 
bla
Category    Other
Price   $229.95
```

Comment: What error? `OutOfMemoryException`? `InvalidCastException`? What?

Comment: nevermind what error, have you tried debugging?

Comment: I recommend to add file example and what do you want to get from it. Just a note, one of the most hilarious lines of code in SO `int a = Convert.ToInt16(s.Length);`.

Comment: Substring's off, then. Could you show us an excerpt from the data list? Also, File.ReadAllLines >>>> StreamReader + manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("data.txt");
List<string> Spec = new List<string>();
while (!file.EndOfStream)
{
    if(file.ReadLine().Contains("Spec")) 
    {
        Spec.Add(s.Substring(5, s.Length - 5));
    }
}
```

That might work.

Comment: Yes, it's work.Thanks! But I need to use regular expressions.

Comment: @user2395751 This is the STUPIDEST task to which use regex for. You don't need regex to find if there's a string in there that is then followed by a space...

Comment: @user2395751 You can just change `if(s.Contains("Spec")) {` to `if(s.Contains("Spec ")) {` if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance I need to get all between Spec and Category. That's why I use Regular Expresion. But i first want to make this to work.

Comment: @user2395751 Your current regex doesn't do that... Anyways, just wrap it in a Regex.IsMatch instead then.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Ok this works, thanks. How to get all between Spec and Category, not just a line?

Comment: @user2395751 Sorry, you're meant to make a new question if you're asking another question. It's the rules, sorry!

Answer (score 3):

This may helps:

```
var result = System.IO.File
    .ReadAllLines(@"data.txt")
    .Where(i => i.Contains("Spec"))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: `Spec\\s` is regular expression, not exact contents of a line

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your example text file, you are starting substring one character late.
The extra character is there as a string is zero-indexed

```
string part = s.Substring(4, s.Length - 4);
```

*My test code*

```
 string s = "Spec    This ... bla bla"; 
 Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(4,s.Length-4));
 Console.ReadLine();

output:=      This ... bla bla
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread has been solved already but as an alternative if you want to use regex a little bit tuning is required in your existing code:

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"data.txt");
List<String> Spec= new List<String>();
while (file.EndOfStream != true)
{
    string s = file.ReadLine();
    Match m = Regex.Match(s, "(?<=Spec\s)(.)+");
    if (m.Success)
    {
        Spec.Add(m.ToString());
    }

    s = String.Empty; // do not forget to free the space you occupied.
}
```

Here:

```
(?<=Spec\s) : This part looks for the text "Spec " in line. 
              Also known as positive look behind.

(.)+        : If first part satisfies take the whole line as a matched string. "." matches 
              every thing except newline.
```

Hope it will help you even after you have solved this problem.