# How to match all between two words with regular expression

Tags: regex, expression

I have this:

```
ID  560
Spec    This ... bla bla 

blah...
blah... +#@%
bla bla 43
bla ~
Category    Other
Price   $259.95 


ID  561
Spec    more blah blah...

blah...
blah... @#$^Y%
bla bla 
bla
Category    Other
Price   $229.95
```

Need to get all between `Spec` and `Category`.

This almost work `[.[:punct:]\r\n\s\t]+[^Category]+` but in Notepad++ i need in C#.

Comment: Asking the same question again, doesn't help when you do it within a hour...

Comment: @B8vrede The same question? Where?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628041/find-all-lines-that-contains-given-string The difference is the fact that you show your own effort in C#.

Comment: @B8vrede No, you are wrong. Just read the comments there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Perl, it's as simple as `/Spec(.*?)Category/gs`. I don't know regular expressions in C#, but you are looking for a non-greedy match-all between those two words.